# How do I create a list from a column of a file?

Tags: python

I want to create a list from a specific column of a file, for example a csv file. How would I append each value in a column without knowing the index?

I created a for loop to find the index of the specific column I want to append to the list, but it does not seem to be correct. I need to somehow make use of the ".split()" method. Much help appreciated :)

```
filename = open(file_name)
row = filename.readline()
index1 = 0
index2 = 0
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i, value in enumerate(row.split(",")):
   if value is "value1":
      index1 = i
   elif str(value) is "value2":
       index2 = i

rows = filename.readlines()
for value in rows:
   list1.append(int(value.split(",")[index1]))
   list2.append(int(value.split(",")[index2]))
```

Example file:

```
a,b,value1,value2

1,2,3,4

4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Have you considered using pandas? You could read the whole file, turn it into a pandas DataFrame and then select just one column of that data frame. This would return you a pandas series, which is easy to turn into a conventional python series.

Comment: I need to somehow make use of the .split() method

Comment: Why? Is this an assignment?

Comment: yea haha I've been stuck for ages...

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what your data looks like?

Comment: @oznaprazzi : Doesn't my answer help you? I just saw you have updated your Question to include .split() as well

Comment: @oznaprazzi : Updated my answer

Comment: @sobek Just updated the question with example file

Comment: @oznaprazzi : Is row having the first line only of the file? And can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: @PriyanshGoel yes, and from the code above it just takes the first column - it's not changing the index1 and index2 at all.

Comment: @oznaprazzi : I have updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to add first column value of the csv file only to the list, then you can do this:

```
import csv
lst=[]
 with open('fl.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...        lst.add(row[1]);
```

Since you have to use split, do this :

```
ans = []
file = open("sample.csv")
text = file.read()
lst = text.split("\n")
for l in lst:
    p = l.split(",")
    ans.add(p[1])
```

PS : I have assumed your input file like :

```
hello,hi,bye
wow,nice,good
....
```

For your code to work, instead of comparing strings with is use ==.

```
if value == "value1"
```

is will return True if two variables point to the same object, == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

Comment: that's exactly what i've got... but yours is just easier to read. Thanks for the answer anyway, much appreciated :)

Comment: @oznaprazzi        What is the error you are getting? Because the code I have posted is working for me. Can you try with my code once

Comment: but I need to find the index of the column "value1" and "value2" first? I tried putting in just a number for the index and that works fine. But when I try to put the index that I need for the column it just doesn't work.

Comment: @oznaprazzi       Can you show how are you taking row as input?

Comment: @oznaprazzi : Instead of comparing strings by "is", use "==". if value == "value1". Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks so much!! So it was just a small bug... wow... took me long enough haha

Comment: Yeah! Even I didn't pay attention to that tiny thing. But you learn that way!